# How to enter the Digital Ocean token?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have DigitalOcean tool installed and would like to initialze it. On the https://github.com/digitalocean/doctl#authenticating-with-digitalocean,
it describes as follows, enter `doctl auth init` and it will prompt the text:

```
DigitalOcean access token: your_DO_token
```

Is there a way to enter the token via Ansible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [very next paragraph under the one you linked to](https://github.com/digitalocean/doctl#logging-in-to-multiple-digitalocean-accounts) it says:

> The `--access-token` flag or `DIGITALOCEAN_ACCESS_TOKEN` variable are acknowledged

so presumably:

```yaml
    - command: doctl compute droplet list
      environment:
        DIGITALOCEAN_ACCESS_TOKEN: your_DO_token
```